# How to hide URL from link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem and I am a bit of a noob to coding but can do HTML ok-ish. So ok, How do I remove the # from my url, currently it is /#contact but I just want /contact. There is an option in my custom.js to hide the hash but when I do that, the /{pagename} disappears and all I see in the address bar is my domain. It's a landing page with javascript so they aren't pages as such, it just scrolls down the page to the correct section.

So I have seen somewhere that I need to add return false to something like click event? I can't find this enywhere in any of the js files. The other thing was the window.location.href but can't find that either.

Here is the only thing I've found in all of my js files.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* navigation local scroll  ----------- */
        jQuery("ul.nav").localScroll({ 
                event:'click', 
                hash:true,
                easing:'easeInQuad', 
                duration:1000,
                offset:-45
        });
```

So in essence, what do I need to do to remove the hash.

Comment: Yes I have, I explained above. When I do this, the /{pagename} disappears and all I see is my domain

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, sorry. It seemed clear to me but oh well.

Comment: I'm not sure I really follow what you are trying to achieve, but if you simply want the browser navigation bar to display your URL without the hashtag (so that if the user refreshes the page, it will load at the top), you could try something like this: `window.history.pushState('null', 'null', '/contact');`

Answer (score 0):

First, some explanations: `#contact` at the end of your URL, means that your browser will try to reach an element in your HTML which have the `id` attribute equals to "contact".

Next, your solutions:

You won't be able to only remove the hash before `content` with only client technology (i.e: javascript), you need to go through your server to rewrite your URL (e.g: using Apache Rewrite module).

But indeed, what you could do, if you don't mind about losing `content` in your URL, is to prevent the URL from changing when you scroll to this element in your javascript, using `event.preventDefault();`... or with your localScroll stuff, it can be done by setting the `hash` option to `false` :

```
jQuery("ul.nav").localScroll({ 
                event:'click', 
                hash:false, // oh yeah
                easing:'easeInQuad', 
                duration:1000,
                offset:-45
        });
```

Comment: _“you need to go through your server to rewrite your URL”_ – well that would kinda defeat the purpose of having all content reside within one document in the first place. And there is of course a client-side solution to this – the _HTML5 History API_.

Comment: Hmmm I've already done the false and I don't want to lose content, I'm a set designer for TV and Theatre so I give URL's out for certain sections of my site a LOT so losing content is not good for me. It's of paramount importance that I have content and the hash to be not present.

Comment: @CBroe actually I was pretty sure that something like this exists, I don't have the courage to edit my answer though, thank you for notice. @user3808773 maybe you could take a look at the `HTML5 History API` as @CBroe pointed out